# reshaping duplicate rows as column headers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to reshape a dataframe using tidyR .Below is the dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame(class_name=c("date","date","educational","qualif","date","date",               "educational","qualif"),
        text_val=c("2000","2003","ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY",
           "Master of Science, Computer Science","1996","2000",
           "MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY",
           "Bachelor of Science, Mechanical Engineering"))
```

I would like the data to look like the below image:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using `tidyverse`. We basically group every 4 rows and spread. However, we need to make names in `class_name` unique first, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
    group_by(grp = rep(seq(n()/4), each = 4)) %>% 
    mutate(class_name = make.unique(as.character(class_name))) %>% 
    spread(class_name, text_val) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(educational, qualif, date, date.1)
```

Which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 4
>                           educational                                      qualif   date date.1
> *                              <fctr>                                      <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
> 1    ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY         Master of Science, Computer Science   2000   2003
> 2 MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY Bachelor of Science, Mechanical Engineering   1996   2000
> ```

Comment: This is brilliant!! Answer accepted.I am new to tidyverse , looks like a great package. Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `reshape` (less elegant than Sotos' solution):

```
data <- data.frame(class_name=c("date","date","educational","qualif","date","date",               "educational","qualif"),
        text_val=c("2000","2003","ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY",
           "Master of Science, Computer Science","1996","2000",
           "MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY",
           "Bachelor of Science, Mechanical Engineering"))
nrec <- 4
data$id <- rep(1:2, each=nrec)
data$time <- rep(1:4, nrow(data)/nrec)

df <- reshape(data, v.names="text_val", idvar="id", direction="wide")[,-1]
names(df) <- c("id","date1","date2","educational","qualif")
df

#   id date1 date2                         educational                                      qualif
# 1  1  2000  2003    ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY         Master of Science, Computer Science
# 5  2  1996  2000 MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY Bachelor of Science, Mechanical Engineering
```

Comment: Note that the base R `reshape` function works fine with your code, so you don't need to load any libraries.

Comment: @lmo Right! Thank you !

Comment: @MarcoSandri: Thanks for sharing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here is also a solution using `dcast()` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, rn := .I + 3L][
  , dcast(.SD , rn %/% 4L ~ class_name, toString, value.var = "text_val")]
```

> ```
>    rn       date                         educational                                      qualif
> 1:  1 2000, 2003    ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY         Master of Science, Computer Science
> 2:  2 1996, 2000 MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY Bachelor of Science, Mechanical Engineering
> ```

Note that `toString()` is used as aggregation function so that the duplicate dates are *concatenated in one column*. This is motivated by the fact that the two `date` columns in OP's  expected output share the same name which may indicate that the expected output is only for display and no further processing of the `date` values is required.

---

If column order matters and `rn` isn't required, the output can be beautified to better match OP's expected result:

```
lvl <- c("educational", "qualif", "date")
setDT(data)[, rn := .I + 3L][, class_name := factor(class_name, levels = lvl)][
  , dcast(.SD , rn %/% 4L ~ class_name, toString, value.var = "text_val")][, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>                            educational                                      qualif       date
> 1:    ILLINOIS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY         Master of Science, Computer Science 2000, 2003
> 2: MAHARASHTRA INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY Bachelor of Science, Mechanical Engineering 1996, 2000
> ```

Comment: Thanks for posting.